# Filtering spark dataframe by a dictionary of lists iteratively

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dictionary which looks something like this `a_dict={"E1":["a",10,20,"red"],"E2":["b", 7, 14,"green"],"E3":["c",40,50,"blue"]]` but much longer, I want to filter a spark dataframe with each list tuple at the same time. let's see an example of the dataframe:

```
+----------------------+
|   User| value| color |
+----------------------+
|  a|     12|       red|
|  a|     21|       red|
|  b|      8|     green|
|  b|     13|     green|
|  c|     41|      blue|
|  b|     72|       red|
|  c|     52|      blue|
|  a|     13|    yellow|
+----------------------+
```

What I am doing right now is:

```
for key, value in a_dict.items():
  df=df.filter((df.user == value[0]) 
          & (df.value > value[1]) 
          & (df.value< value[2]) 
          &  (df.color==value[3]))
```

dummy df output should be like this:

```
+----------------------+
|   User| value| color |
+----------------------+
|  a|     12|       red|
|  b|      8|     green|
|  b|     13|     green|
|  c|     41|      blue|
+----------------------+
```

I was wondering if there's a faster way without using a for loop and reassignig the dataframe each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dataframe from the dictionary values, and do a semi-join to filter the original dataframe:

```
a_dict = {"E1":["a",10,20,"red"],"E2":["b", 7, 14,"green"],"E3":["c",40,50,"blue"]}

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(a_dict.values(), ['user', 'value1', 'value2', 'color'])

result = df.join(df2, 
    (df['user'] == df2['user']) & 
    (df['color'] == df2['color']) & 
    (df['value'].between(df2['value1'], df2['value2'])),
    'left_semi'
)

result.show()
+----+-----+-----+
|User|value|color|
+----+-----+-----+
|   c|   41| blue|
|   b|    8|green|
|   b|   13|green|
|   a|   12|  red|
+----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: It works perfectly just one thing if you don't mind, let's say i have one more value in df2,
`df2 = spark.createDataFrame(a_dict.values(), ['user', 'value1', 'value2', 'color','ID'])`
how would i go about retaining the ID value for each match in df?
results should then have one more column with the relative ID, is it possible somehow? sorry i'm not so well versed with joins

Comment: then you could try doing a `left` join instead of a `left_semi` join. If that's still not successful, you can ask a new question and provide the necessary details.